# How to disable primeNg TreeTable Parent Node

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, treetable

I'm using PrimeNG tree table control. I need when the user select a child node, disable all other parent nodes which do not belong to the current selected child node.

How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="_files" [columns]="_cols" dataKey="name" [resizableColumns]="true"
             [(contextMenuSelection)]="_selectedNode" [contextMenu]="cm"
             [style]="{width:'800px'}" scrollHeight="200px">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" ttResizableColumn>
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">

    <tr [ttContextMenuRow]="rowNode">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" (dblclick)="dd()" (click)="RowClicked($event,rowNode)">
        <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0" class="pi user-set"></p-treeTableToggler>
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example?